# Read list of zlib archives

Tags: python, file, zlib

I have a file that contains many zlib archives in itself.
Structure of the file looks like:

```
+-------------------------+
|+-----------------------+|
||     CMF+FLG (78DA)    ||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||...compressed data 1...||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||        ADLER32        ||
|+-----------------------+|
|
|+-----------------------+|
||     CMF+FLG (78DA)    ||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||...compressed data 2...||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||        ADLER32        ||
|+-----------------------+|
|
|+-----------------------+|
||     CMF+FLG (78DA)    ||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||...compressed data 3...||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||        ADLER32        ||
|+-----------------------+|
|                         |
|.........................|
|                         |
|+-----------------------+|
||     CMF+FLG (78DA)    ||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||...compressed data n...||
|+-----------------------+|
|+-----------------------+|
||        ADLER32        ||
|+-----------------------+|
+-------------------------+
```

And I need iterate over all those archive and extract them.
I tried following code but this extracts only first archive from file.

```
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, 'r') as compressed:
        with open(filename + '-decompressed', 'w') as expanded:
            data = zlib.decompress(compressed.read())
            expanded.write(data)
```

Comment: It seems as if you could just split the file on the `CMD+FLG` marker, although it's not clear to me what protects you from the same sequence being contained in one of the compressed data sections.

Comment: How I can split without removing delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a series of decompression objects like this:

```
import zlib

with open(filename, 'rb') as compressed:
    data = compressed.read()
    file_no = 0

    while data:
        d = zlib.decompressobj()
        with open('{}_decompressed.{}'.format(filename, file_no), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(d.decompress(data))
        data = d.unused_data
        file_no += 1
```

This will take a single file containing multiple concatenated zlib compressed files and decompress each one to a separate file with *"_decompressed.n"* appended to the original file name.

The key is to use the decompression object's `unused_data` attribute to determine whether there remains any uncompressed data in the string.